# Android local variable get's lost when using camera intent

Tags: android, android-image

I'm dealing with a random problem which related to camera usage. Before I call camera intent - I generate UUID to store file with this name. I store this UUID in private variable like so:

```
private String requestedFileName;
```

When camera done - I'm processing this file, looks something like this:

```
public void onPictureTaken(int index)
    {
        //First of all - remember picture in database for reference.
        FileData.InsertFile(mContext, UUID.fromString(requestedFileName));

        //Reduce taken picture if needed, otherwise let it be original.
        if (Preferences.getImageSize(mContext) > 0)
        {
            Imaging.scaleImageFile(mContext, requestedFileName, Preferences.getImageSize(mContext));
        }
```

I see users report issue exception that boils down to **requestedFileName == null** when **onPictureTaken** called

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:210)
 at com.idatt.views.FourImagesView.onPictureTaken(FourImagesView.java:151)
 at com.idatt.views.TrailerUnitView.onPictureTaken(TrailerUnitView.java:233)
```

Everything works good on my phone (Nexus S) and in emulator. But users report this exception and I'm not sure why this is happening..

Comment: Are you sure you always store a file name in the variable requestedFileName? It cannot be null?

Comment: Yeah, unless it's completely stupid bug - I'm 100% sure it cannot happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this happen on the Nexus phones, and some others.  If you use DDMS to watch what is going on, I bet you'll see that your process is actually being terminated and then restarted.  Thus your local state is being lost.  You need to persist it, since Android can basically kill your process and restart it whenever it wants if you switch to a new task (and most of the camera capture intents set the NEWTASK flag).

If your class is an `Activity` you can use [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to store your filename, then read it back out of the `Bundle` you get in [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29).

If you are not an `Activity` you can use the `SharedPreferences` store as a temporary place to save the filename:

```
private static void saveTempFileName(Context context, String filename) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("whatever", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("com.yourstuff.whatever", filename);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't watch it since I don't have those phones. I was thinking about persisting state, however I'm not sure how to do it in my case. This is not Activity, it is my custom View (extends LinearLayout). Do I have to expose methods to persist state and call those from parent Activity?

Comment: Yeah, well I've seen it happen on those phones.  Just write your filename to `SharedPreferences` and read it back in your handler if your member variable is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

As @jeffamaphone noted you are probably having issues with app configuration changes. Application configuration change happens when something happens that affects the runtime environment of your app. Most notably this are: orientation change or keyboard hide/show.

Try this: start your app, invoke the Camera app (via your app action), change orientation, return to your app (via appropriate action). Does this sequence produce the error? Then you have issues with configuration change - when orientation changes usually (depending on your app settings) Android system restarts (kills and creates new instance) your Activity, which probably creates all new Views (without UUID set).

See [handling configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Comment: Thanks! Check goes to jeffamaphone but you did help me(upvote). I forgot about orientation. My app if fixed portrait, so I made it tiltable and was able to emulate exception right away.