# Android manage configuration changes(state) in custom view

Tags: android

This is follow up to: [Android local variable get's lost when using camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179706/android-local-variable-gets-lost-when-using-camera-intent)

Proper way to do it is to handle `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` like shown here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CompoundButton.java

Here is my code:

```
static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState
    {
        private String requestedFileName;
        private UUID[] mImages = new UUID[4];

        SavedState(Parcelable superState)
        {
          super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in)
        {
          super(in);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
        {
          super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        }

        //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
            new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>()
            {
              public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in)
              {
                return new SavedState(in);
              }
              public SavedState[] newArray(int size)
              {
                return new SavedState[size];
              }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
    {
        //begin boilerplate code that allows parent classes to save state
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        //end

        ss.requestedFileName = this.requestedFileName;
        ss.mImages = this.mImages;

        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)
    {
        //begin boilerplate code so parent classes can restore state
        if(!(state instanceof SavedState))
        {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }

        SavedState ss = (SavedState)state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        //end

        this.requestedFileName = ss.requestedFileName;
        this.mImages = ss.mImages;

        RestoreImageState();
    }
```

Now to my question. This code seems to work properly and it handles all state changes without a problem. HOWEVER, if you look at **SavedState.writeToParcel** and **SavedState.SavedState** you will notice that I do not store my variables there. Do I have to? Why? Problem is that I understand how to wrteToParcel and my data types match. But reading out of parcel not so clear with complex types. And in my tests it wasn't called.

EDIT:

Does this look correct for save/retreive order?

```
private SavedState(Parcel in)
        {
          super(in);
          this.mName = in.readString();
          this.mIndex = in.readInt();
          this.mApplicableDamages = (String[])in.readValue(null);
          this.mSelectedDamages = (boolean[])in.readValue(null);                            
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
        {
          super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
          out.writeString(this.mName);
          out.writeInt(this.mIndex);
          out.writeArray(this.mApplicableDamages);
          out.writeBooleanArray(this.mSelectedDamages);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save these variables in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore them in `onRestoreInstanceState()` later if they're part of your view's state and you don't want to lose them when a parent activity is recreated.

The variables may be lost because when the configuration change happens the parent activity is destroyed and a new activity object is recreated. This new object is receive the previously saved state. And if you don't add some variables to the state the won't be restored.

As to the writing complex types to and reading the from `Parcel` you can implement `Parcelable` for some parts of the complex type. Or you can just decompose the complex type to the primitive (parcelable) fields and store this fields one by one. In your case `UUID[]` can be stored in `Parcel` as `Serializable` or you can convert `UUID[]` to `ParcelUuid[]` and store this array as parcelable array.

And a few words about `SavedState` implementation. The fields in `SavedState` will not be saved if you don't add them to `Parcel`. So you have to write the to `Parcel` in `SavedState.writeToParcel()` method. And also you need to read them back in `SavedState(Parcel)` constructor.

```
static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState
{
    private String requestedFileName;
    private UUID[] mImages = new UUID[4];

    SavedState(Parcelable superState)
    {
        super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in)
    {
        super(in);
        requestedFileName = in.readString();
        mImages = (UUID[])in.readSerializable();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
    {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeString(requestedFileName);
        out.writeSerializable(mImages);
    }

    //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>()
        {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in)
            {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size)
            {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: So, do I need to use SavedState.writeToParcel? And how to duplicate behavior when it will be called?

Comment: Yes, you do have to call it. And in this method you need to add all the state fields to `Parcel`. I don't understand your question about duplication.

Comment: When I write to parcel - there is no "tag" or "name". If I want to save let's say 2 strings. string1 and string2 and than when I need to get them back in SavedState.SavedState - how do I know which one is which?

By duplication I mean how do I reproduce in emulator or on device so writeToParcel get's called? Like I said in ordiginal post - they never get called in my debugger. And it seems like everything working fine

Comment: I've added some information about `SavedState` implementation.

Comment: Pixie, can you take my code and modify it to show how I read/write those 2 properties? I guess my main problem is that I don't see how I retreive them properly? There is no "tag". Is it FIFO or FILO?

Comment: You have to read fields in the same order you write them. I think the easiest way to make Android call `SavedState.writeToParcel()` is to terminate the process of your app using a third-party task manager and relaunching the app from recent apps window (using long home button press).

Comment: I edited original post. See if code I added on a bottom looks correct? (order in which I save retreive)

Comment: Order is OK, but you should use `writeStringArray()`/`readStringArray()` for `mApplicableDamages` and `writeBooleanArray()`/`readBooleanArray()` for `mSelectedDamages`.

Comment: There is no readStringArray() on Parcel and there is no readBooleanArray(). Any suggestion what might be wrong? It's Android 2.1
Спасибо за помощь! Родина вас не забудет :)

Comment: Ok, I got it. I didn't have intellisense because readStringArray and readBooleanArray do not return value, they require reference to work with.